# Is there any way to check whether a given class type belongs to Java object or custom object

Tags: java, class, reflection, types

I was searching for any ways to check whether the type of the given attribute of a class is of custom object type (for eg., Person) or Java object (for eg., String, Long, primitive types as well) type. If instanceof is used, it will be hectic checking all of the Java types. Can anyone suggest a way to check, if anything as such exists.

Comment: Java has many build in classes and interfaces like `List` for instance. How should your code react for lets say `ArrayList` instance?

Comment: Thatswhat I want to know. In simple words, if my custom class is having 5 attributes of the types - String, int, Long, List, custom object. If this is the case, using reflection I can get the type of the individual fields. But after getting the type, is there any way to identify whether the type is of in-built java type or custom type ?

Comment: @Sarath But **what do you consider "in-built java type"?**  As discussed by several people here, there are many possible answers to that question, depending on what **you** need it for.

Comment: So, one thing what I can understand from the answer people gave for this question is that, there is no direct way to check whether the class belongs to in-built java type or custom object, rather checking for the regex of class package declaration is the only way. Correct me if I am wrong please.

Comment: @Sarath What problem are you trying to solve? If this is about persisting value objects, you should take a look at [JPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Persistence_API), in particular the way it uses annotations to define meaningful, persistent fields

Comment: @Sarath No, that is not right.  The problem is that you are not defining your terms, "in-built" vs. "custom".  The answerers are left to guess at what you mean by this, and package name is one sensible definition.  I would suggest **A)** defining your terms more specifically, and **B)** defining what actual problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Java is very much "built on itself". Much of the SDK could be considered both "custom" or "built-in" depending on which way you are looking at it.

For instance, `Exception` is built in to Java but also written in Java.  You could write similar code yourself, however based on what you've said I am guessing you would consider it a "Java object".

Similarly, `ArrayList` is also written in Java, but because it's a utility class, I'm guessing you would consider it "custom", though I'm not sure, since it is still included in the SDK.

Without knowing exactly what you are looking for, the closest grouping that I can guess based on what you've said (`String`, `Long`, etc.) is the `java.lang` package.  In the [words of the SDK documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/package-summary.html) itself, the `java.lang` package:

> Provides classes that are fundamental to the design of the Java programming language.

You can check if the package name of the class for the object is in `java.lang`:

```
static class A {
    
}

public static void main (String[] args) {
    String test1 = "";
    A test2 = new A();
    int test3 = 3;

    System.out.println(isJavaLang(test1));
    System.out.println(isJavaLang(test2));
    System.out.println(isJavaLang(test3));
}

public static boolean isJavaLang(Object check) {
    return check.getClass().getName().startsWith("java.lang");
}
```

### [Working example](http://ideone.com/ABhEiC)

Comment: If this is the case, for primitive types and classes from javax.* and other packages for example, this wont work. Just a random example. javax.swing.ActionMap c = new javax.swing.ActionMap();
System.out.println(c.getClass().getName()); will return javax.swing.ActionMap

Comment: @Sarath But those aren't "primitive".  I've updated my answer to explain.  Before I thought you were looking for the "fundamental" Java objects, but now it sounds like you are looking for anything defined by the SDK?  Please clarify that requirement before you dismiss whether this can help you or not.

Comment: @Sarath Also, actually it will work for primitives.  Primitives are [autoboxed](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) when passed to function calls requiring `Object`, and the wrapper classes are all within `java.lang`.

Comment: One answer was posted by Pshemo. This I tried and its working. Can you update on this please. Its not using the package name but the implementationVendor and implementationTitle. Similar to your answer but different. What you gave is also working. But the thing is, its more like listing all the possible packages. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Sarath Sure, that sounds like a good solution, except that the "implementation vendor" or "implementation title" might vary dependent on the JRE whereas package name will most likely always be "java".  If you would like it to return 'true' for anything in the SDK, you could compare it against "java" instead of "java.lang".

Answer (score 4):

There's no fail-safe method to do this. As others said, Java builds a lot on regular classes.

I guess that, appart from primitives, it all boils down to your own definition of "JDK's classes" vs "my classes" vs "3rd party classes".

@splungebob's solution works for your own, single tree-branch classes.

I would think that classes from the following packages can be safely, if minimallistically, regarded as JDK's:

```
java.lang.*
java.*
javax.*
com.sun.*
com.oracle.*
```

You might also add some common 3rd parties like org.apache.*

Answer (score 4):

Try maybe using implementation <strike>vendor</strike> title of package that object is coming from. It seems that standard Java packages have this value set to <strike>`"Oracle Corporation"`.</strike>  `"Java Runtime Environment"`.

```
public static boolean isJavaLang(Object check) {
    if (check == null)// lets say that null comes from JRE
        return true;

    return isJavaLang(check.getClass());
}

public static boolean isJavaLang(Class<?> check) {

    Package p = check.getClass().getPackage();

    if (p == null) // default package is package for users classes
        return false;

    String title = p.getImplementationTitle();
    if (title == null)// no title -> class not from Oracle
        return false;

    // System.out.println(p.getImplementationVendor());
    // System.out.println(p.getImplementationTitle());
    return title.equals("Java Runtime Environment");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that answer. I see "Sun Microsystems, Inc." for the implementationVendor for Java classes. This was really helpful.

Comment: @Sarath Could you show from which package/object you get this vendor? It seems that comes from some legacy class and Oracle didn't change it from Sun to Oracle. Anyway try maybe `p.getImplementationVendor()` instead and compare it with `"Java Runtime Environment"`.

Comment: Thanks again. implementationTitle returning "Java Runtime Environment" and implementationVendor returning "Sun Microsystems, Inc." for some random java in-build classes I tried, and null for custom objects and third party objects. The java classes I tried - SwingUtilities.class, ArrayList.class, List.class. I'm using JRE 1.6.

Comment: As reference this data is not magic. Those values are actually from `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`. If the entry `Implementation-Title` is not set then this API will return `null`. `rt.jar` manifest declares : `Implementation-Title: Java Runtime Environment` along with other information such as the vendor, version, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure I got your question right...

The [java.lang.Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) class features some tools you can use.

The [isPrimitive()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isPrimitive%28%29) function

> Determines if the specified Class object represents a primitive type.
>   There are nine predefined Class objects to represent the eight primitive types and void. These are created by the Java Virtual Machine, and have the same names as the primitive types that they represent, namely boolean, byte, char, short, int, long, float, and double.
>
> These objects may only be accessed via the following public static final variables, and are the only Class objects for which this method returns true.

As for the other classes, there is no such thing as a "Java object" - every object is a Java object... But you could for example check if the name of the class in question begins with `java.lang.` prefix, but the [java.lang package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/package-summary.html) contains a lot different things too, not only the basic datatypes you'd like to find.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like:

```
public static boolean isJavaObject(Object obj)
{
  return (! obj.getClass().getName().startsWith("my.package"));
}
```

where `"my.package"` is the head of your package heirarchy.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that your own classes aren't located within packages whose names start with `java*`:

```
public static <T> boolean isJDKClass(T t) {
     return t.getClass().getPackage().getName().startsWith("java");
}
```